# freeing general linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to build a generic function that will free a general linked list. I have several structs, and I would like this function to get a pointer to the head, regardless of it's type, and delete the entire linked list.

How can I do that?

Should the decleration be something like that:

```
void FreeLinkedList(void *first)
```

thanks

Comment: because of the dependencies, it's better to start at the tail end. If you start with the head, traverse the list to the end then start deleting. Or be careful about making copies of pointers before deleting things as you traverse the list. I'm sure you can show more effort (code), then ask the community for help with any remaining problems.

Comment: Doesn't starting at the end depend on the list being doubled linked?

Comment: I do not have a problem of writing the code for a specific strtucture (I am using one sided linked-list), the problem begins when I want to vary the struct,  as I wrtoe.

Comment: is it possible that the individual node can have any pointer member, other than `next` ?

Comment: My strcuts have some fields, and at the end the pointer next (of this same struct type).

Comment: Ok. check my answer. See if you can fit your code as per the restrictions I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that there is no pointer member in the possible `struct`s, of which the linked list is made, then you can probably use below code:

```
/*Actual structures definition*/
struct A{
   struct A* next; // MUST be first element.
   int some_data;
   int some_other_data;
   float some_more_data;
   // int* pointer_to_some_other_data; // NOT allowed, if it is malloc'ed data, expected to be freed by your function.
   int some_data_array[50]; // This is OK. array is part of the same struct. & it's different from pointer.
   /*etc...*/
}

struct B{
   struct B* next; // MUST be first element.
   int some_other_data;
   float some_more_data;
   /*etc...*/
}

/*
  struct C definition...
  struct D definition...
  etc
*/

/*Generic struct definition*/
struct generic_struct{
    struct generic_struct* next; // MUST be first element. (It's the only element here.)
}

/*Generic free function*/
void FreeLinkedList(void *first){
     if(first==NULL) return;
     struct generic_struct *next=((struct generic_struct*)first)->next;
     free(first); // assumes that there is no pointer data in struct_A or struct_B, except `next`.
     FreeLinkedList(next);
}

//Usage:
FreeLinkedList(my_linked_list_head);
my_linked_list_head=NULL; // Don't MISS this. Alternately (& preferrably), you can change the `FreeLinkedList` function prototype to accept `void**` & do NULL assignment in the function.
```

Notes:

1. The linked list being passed to `FreeLinkedList` must have all elements from `heap`. it makes no sense, if some elements are from `stack/global/static`
2. The linked list can also have mix of `struct A` & `struct B` members.
3. structs A & B cannot have any other pointer type variable, which may have got `malloc`ed. Else, who would `free` it?
4. The `next` element must be the first element in all the `struct`s.

Comment: Without knowing how long the linked list might can be, isn't it possible for a recursive `FreeLinkedList` implementation to result in stack overflow?

Comment: Thanks, but I do have another pointers to malloc'ed data in some of my strucrs. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: well, you are right; but a single stack frame in this is only 4 or 8 bytes. (only one pointer. We can either make it static, just to avoid stack overflow (dirty way), or the recursion can be easily converted to a while loop.)

Comment: @mike: Create `free` functions (with same looking prototype) for all the structs, like `void free_struct_A(void* struct_A_ptr)`, which properly delete ONE node of that struct type. Add a function pointer in all the data structs, to point to these respective free functions. Then instead of calling `free` in `FreeLinkedList`, call that function using function pointer. (overhead, but should work.)

Comment: @Mike: Google `unions`, and write a `FreeLinkedList` to work on your structs as a union. You could also work out a comprehensive way of padding the bits in all your structs, and define the generic struct to have the same amount of pointers as the actual struct with the most pointers. Then just `free` those prior to freeing the struct

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int FreeLinkedList(void ** pfirst)
```

1. Return `int` to be able to comminucate error conditions.
2. Pass in the address of the head/tail, to be able to return a properly re-initialised pointer being set to `NULL` instead of leaving the caller with a dangeling pointer.

Comment: @zoska: At least those Murphy didn't informed you of yet. ;-)

Comment: As long as free does not return anything I don't really see what kind of error someone could return with this function